# Ubuntu find apt-get install scsitools script

Tags: ubuntu, apt

VM Ubuntu 14.04

big pic: trying to add HDD without rebooting guest,
created - no problem

med pic: get Ubuntu to recognize new HDD.
apt-get install scsitools.
works, great, installed.

small pic: find script.
rescan-scsi-bus.sh
rescan-scsi-bus.sh: command not found

Comment: Have found /var/cache/apt/archives. Pkg is there... script?

Comment: This question may find a better answer on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), if you manage to migrate it there. Both these places are in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Thanks francis for the links, AskUbuntu helped, and thanks also @Byaxy, i discovered it there also just before coming back here to see your answer, the missing .sh fooled me earlier

Answer (score 0):

Try  /sbin/rescan-scsi-bus 
If i'm not mistaken this is a default install dir for these tools